# SQLite database connection with java in NetBeans

Tags: java, database, sqlite, netbeans

I am trying to connect the sqlite3 with java in NetBeans but when I run it, it shows the message that is written in the exception.

```
public Statement connection() {
    
    try {
        
        String url = "jdbc:sqlit:F:\\Work\\Coding\\Java\\sqlitconnection";
        
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        
        st = con.createStatement();
        
        System.out.println("Connection Sucessful.");
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        System.out.println("Connection Error.");
        
    }
    
    return st;
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Sqlitconnection obj = new Sqlitconnection();
    
    obj.connection();
    
}
```

This is the result-

```
Connection Error.
```

I have imported all of the libraries but cannot understand what's wrong.

Comment: Look into `e` With a debugger.

Comment: You should print the whole stack trace.  It has more information than the message you print.  Take a look at this: https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/connect-to-sqlite-via-jdbc

Comment: Missing letter `e`.  `"jdbc:sqlit:..."` -> `"jdbc:sqlite:..."`

Answer (score 0):

sqlitconnection is the name of the database? if so have you tried to add the .db at the bottom?
like this :

`String url = "jdbc:sqlit:F:\\Work\\Coding\\Java\\sqlitconnection.db";`